# error while running java files

Tags: java, compilation

I have two files like `read.java` and `sufer_type.java`. The `surfer_type.java` needs some methods which are present in a `.jar` file. Before executing `surfer_type.java` I need to run `read.java` and use the data from `read.java`. So I used the statement:

```
read r=new read();
```

in `surfer_type.java` and I am compiling `surfer_type.java` like:

```
javac -classpath netcdfAll.jar surfer_type.java:
```

But I am getting an error:

```
surfer_netcdf.java:30: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class read
location: class surfer_netcdf
 read r = new read();
  ^
surfer_netcdf.java:30: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class read 
location: class surfer_netcdf
 read r = new read();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to instantiate a class `read`, which it is telling you does not exist (or rather, it cannot find).

Make sure the class exists and is properly imported in the class where you are trying to use it.

Comment: hi thank you for your reply, i had placed all the files in same folder and had instantiated using read r =new read(); but i cant understand why it is asking for read class again

Comment: A good place to start with Jon's suggestions is to see if the two objects are in the same `package`. At the top of your `surfer_type.java` you should have an `import blah.blah.blah.read` call. Also, keep in mind that it is accepted standard to name classes starting with a capital letter such as `Read` or `SurferType`